# Looping through 3 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

how would I go about looping through this data here:

```
Array ( 
    [reply] => Array (
        [recipient] => Array ( 
            [@msisdn] => 1234123412 
            [@id] => 5b5f9635-15d7-44d8-b1e3-7015hj95c71c 
            )
    ) 
)
```

So I want to get the @mssidn's and the @id's to use like this:

```
foreach($$$){
    $sqldata .= '(' . $last_id . ',' . $msisdn . ',' . $id . '),';
}
```

`$last_id` comes from another function, so just need the two others.
I just can't seem to get it working, so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It's basic key access. `$your_array['reply']['recipient']['@msisdn']`.

Comment: @olvvang, how many `reply`, and `recipient` do you have into the array? or this is the complete array? it is not complete, please provide more data.

Comment: is array structure always the same `'reply', 'recipient'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate your array get the values by key `@msisdn` and `@id`

```
foreach($array as $value) {
  foreach($value as $data) {        
    $sqldata .= '(' . $last_id . ',' . $data['@msisdn'] . ',' . $data['@id'] . '),';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

start the foreach loop at the point in the data structure that you want to process and just loop over the contents of the inner array

```
foreach ($arr['reply'] as $recip){
    $sqldata .= '(' . $last_id . ',' . $recip['@msisdn'] . ',' . $recip['@id'] . '),';
}
```